# Sending an automatic email periodically

Tags: c#, .net, database, postgresql

I have Windows server with PostgreSQL database. I stored in the database employees data including contract expiry date. 
I would like to send an automatic email for each employee 30 days before the expiry date. (Each employee has an email account).
What is the best way to do that?
I am thinking to do the following, Could you please advise if it is the best way, and if, I need answer for the questions:

- Build WinForm C#  application doing:
- Access PostgreSQL everyday( I know how to deal with Postgresql, but `how to make it per each new day (schedule task?)`?)
- Compare machine date with all expiry date in the database
- If the difference equals or less than 30 days, an automatic mail will
  be send to the employee. (`how to send emails using C#`}

Comment: A service would likely be overkill for this.  I'd build out a console app that runs as a scheduled task once a day.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AS @Middas proposed, writing a simple console application would take the responsibility of scheduling outside the application.

A simple console application is OK, scheduled by either Windows Scheduler or a 3rd party scheduler would do.

For sending emails, you could

- use .net provided [SMTPClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx) namespace to send emails
- use 3rd party service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) to schedule a method responsible for sending emails.

Quartz.NET uses cron time to configure when it will execute your code.

In the web site have some examples.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it be easy to create .Net console application which fires query to DB which brings in  all employee record whose contract expiring in 30 days. 
Schedule this using Windows Scheduler to run at a specific time each day.

Now to send an email in C#, try following piece of code.

```
MailMessage mailObj = new MailMessage(strFrom, strTo, strSubject, strBody);
SmtpClient SMTPObj = new SmtpClient(IPAddress,port);
try
{
  SMTPObj.Send(mailObj);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  //Handle Exception
}
```

Hope that helps
Milind

Answer (score 0):

I would do what you suggest with a Windows Service. have the service timer set to 30 seonds, then check whether the time is between 00:00:00 and 00:00:00, send your email. This means you don't have to try to time your `elapsed` event to fire when you need.

Comment: Why check every 30 seconds when the email needs to go out 30 days before expiry?

Comment: It makes it easier to time the sending. Otherwise, if you have it run once per day, you'd need to be precise with the timing of starting the service.

Comment: Well, that's a scheduling problem and I think any scheduler would address that. I would be careful not to fire 48 queries when only one is required. But guess it depends on the context